# 2004 Accord LX cruise control fails intermittently

Tags: honda, accord, cruise-control

2004 Accord LX cruise control fails intermittently on Hwy after crusing around a half hour. Works again next time I drive in order to fail again after driving a half hour next day. Cruise switch replaced twice remains the same. It has been like this for a few months. Can somebody help?

Comment: Have you had the codes read? There may be an intermittant fault causing the ecu to cancel cruise.

Comment: A possible cause is a defective brake light switch. Have someone follow you and see if your brake lights flicker without you applying the brakes.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Shift lever or clutch pedal movement or defective switches of these can also cancel cruise on that model.